# Mapping Unbounded Attributes To Excel Columns

Tags: xml, excel

I am trying to use Microsoft Excel 2003 to manage test files that have historically been kept by my company as raw text.  I would like to use the XML mapping functionality, but am struggling to handle unbounded attributes in Excel.  The relevant part of my schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="TestCommand">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TrialPercenatage" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:simpleContent>
                   <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                       <xs:attribute name="trial" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="TestCommandType" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="parameters" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
</xs:complexType>
```

I am trying to ideally have the individual TestCommands mapped on to rows, but am struggling to figure out how to map the TrialPercentages in such a way as to allow it to be unbounded columns in the spread sheet.  An idea of what I am going for:

```
type   name   parameters    Trial1   Trial2   Trial3   Trial4

action read   arg1=2 arg2=4  33       34       35       36
```

The issue I am having is if I just drag and drop my schema element that is of the TestCommand type, it will only allow me a single Trial column.  I'd like it to map so the Trial headings become the value assigned to the TrialPercentage trial attribute and the values in the columns are mapped to the value of TrialPercentage.  I have tried a couple of things to bludgeon it into working, but to no avail.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: One solution would be to have one `Trial Number` and `Trial Result` column per row. For example, the Trial Number column could contain "Trial1" and the Trial Result column could contain "33". So for the sample data posted you would have four rows with identical type/name/parameters but differing Trial Number and Trial Result values. Not sure how to achieve this via the XML Mapping functionality right now

Comment: The problem with this is with other attributes.  I considered flipping things so that each row would contain trial results, but not all trials will have the same attributes.  I realize I could use optional attributes to reflect these, but the actual trial attributes list has several dozen elements and I would prefer to not need to update the schema if a new one is added.